# multipart form encoding a string with PHP

Tags: php, http, multipart

I am writing PHP code to send XML string data to a site using HTTP post with the encType: multipart/form-data encoding.  I am thinking of using PHP's http_post_data function. Before sending the data, I believe I need to encode it, but I cannot see a PHP function to do this for me, nor do I know how to write such a function myself.

This is what I have so far (but http_request_body_encode() is certainly not the correct function):

```
$options = array('headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'));
$fields = array('operation' =>'doMDUpload', 'login_id' => $doi_username, 'login_passwd' => $doi_password, 
  'area' => ($debug ? "test" : "live"), 'fname' => $writer->outputMemory());
$info = array();
$response = http_post_data($crossref_deposit_url, http_request_body_encode($fields, array()), $options, $info);
```

`$writer->outputMemory` is an XML string containing bibliometric data.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [http_request_body_encode()](http://php.net/http_request_body_encode) would be the correct function. But it is not a core function. It's available with the http pecl extension, that's not even installed per default on PHP 5.3.

It also does not generate a `multipart/form-data` per default (instead x-www-form-urlencode). You can trick it by supplying a fake `$files` array however:

```
print http_request_body_encode(array("field"=>123), array(NULL=>NULL));
```

Now the second problem is that you need to cut out the first line. That's the `Content-Type` with the correct `boundary=` attribute. And that seems fiddly to me.

So better use the [HttpRequest](http://php.net/HttpRequest) class directly, and let it handle the POST encoding **and** sending at once. Alternatively use the PEAR or Zend class, which also work regardless of presence of the HTTP extension module.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer, but it leaves me with a couple of points I don't quite understand:

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer, but it leaves me with a couple of points I don't quite understand: (1)  "you need to cut out the first line. That's the Content-Type with the correct boundary= attribute." Why do I need to do that?  Shouldn't I rather remove my code (line 1 of the code in my question) that sets a header?  (2) If I were to use the HttpRequest class directly, how do I tell it to use multipart/form-data encoding?

Comment: @micrology: You must cut out the content-type line because it would otherwise be the wrong format. The header line must be part of the headers, not content body. I don't know how to force multipart/, maybe with the same $files trick on ::setPostFiles.